# Replacing character after single quote

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the following C# code to modify a lowercase letter to uppercase after a single quote:

```
public virtual string FirstName
{
    get { return _firstName; }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            int pos = value.IndexOf("'", 0);
            int strlength = value.Length - 1;
            if (pos >= 0 && pos != strlength)
            {
                string temp = value[pos + 1].ToString();
                temp = temp.ToUpper();
                value = value.Remove(pos + 1, 1);
                value = value.Insert(pos + 1, temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To me this looks like overkill. Is there an easier way to achieve the desired result:

```
Value: Mc'donald
Expected: Mc'Donald
```

Comment: Would you be willing to use a Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps regular expressions?

```
string value = "Mc'donald";
string found = Regex.Match(value, "'[\\w]").Value;
string result = value.Replace(found, found.ToUpper());

Console.WriteLine(result); // Mc'Donald
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're open to Regex, would this overload of the `Regex.Replace` do what you need?

[Regex.Replace Method (String, MatchEvaluator)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx)

Here's a modified version of the example given at the link above.  I've changed it to use the `'\w` pattern and to return the match in upper case.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class RegExSample
{
static string CapText(Match m)
    {
        // Return the match in upper case
        return m.ToString().ToUpperInvariant();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        string text = "Mc'donald";

        System.Console.WriteLine("text=[" + text + "]");

        Regex rx = new Regex(@"'\w");

        string result = rx.Replace(text, new MatchEvaluator(RegExSample.CapText));

        System.Console.WriteLine("result=[" + result + "]");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here is without regex

```
  int pos = data.IndexOf("'");
  if (pos >= 0 && pos < data.Length - 1)
  {
    StringBuilder sbl = new StringBuilder(data);
    sbl[pos + 1] = char.ToUpper(sbl[pos + 1]);
    data = sbl.ToString();
  }
```

Comment: I think this would only cap the first instance of the single quote too. Could be fixed, but something to consider if `data` has more than one single quote.

Comment: you are right and I am aware of that, it works same as the original code from question